# Distance Point Cloud to Mesh in Python

Tags: python, mesh, point-clouds

I have a large 3D point cloud and a mesh consisting of triangular elements. I need to calculate the minimum distance of every point to the mesh as described in this paper (https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePoint3Triangle3.pdf). However, because of the large number of points and elements a brute force approach is not feasible.

It is my understanding that storing the elements and data points in a tree-structure (e.g. octree), would considerably speed up the calculation.

Is there a Python library that would allow me to do the calculation very efficiently even for a large number of points and elements?

Comment: All code, data, background info, error messages, etc necessary to solve your issue must be included *as text* in the body of your Question. You can read more about SO requirements in the help section, linked to at the top of every page. As is, if the linked-to page becomes unavailable, your Q becomes useless, & quality of SO suffers. Also, nobody wants to click around the internet just to find out what your question is--& not all links can be trusted. Strive to make it as easy & inviting as possible so volunteers choose your Q over another. Code must be a Minimum Viable Example.

Comment: Also, questions asking for library or tutorials are outside the scope of questions SO is designed to handle. There are sister sites in the StackExchange network dedicated to this type of question. Perhaps, you can reword your question so it refers to a specific coding issue, instead of requesting an outside resource?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree).
With KD-tree you can solve your problem in approximately O (N * log (M) * k), where N is the number of points in the point cloud, M is the number of vertices in the mesh, k is the average number of "adjacent" triangles to one vertex.

1. build KD-tree on mesh vertexs:

```
tr = cKDTree(Mesh_vertexs)
```

2. Build a hash table `vertex -> list of "adjoining" triangles`
3. Learn to find the distance between a point and a triangle (if you can't)
   then the pseudocode of the algorithm is extremely simple:

```
for point in point_cloud:
    d,idx_of_point_in_mesh = tree.query(point)
    for triangle in Mesh_Triangles_near_vertex[idx_of_point_in_mesh]:
        d = min(d, distance(triangle,point))
    min_distance[point] = d
```

To estimate the performance, for 10 ^ 6 vertices in a mesh, one query `tree.query (point)` takes on my laptop `27.5 µs ± 235 ns`.
For a cloud of 10 ^ 6 points, the time will be `27.5 µs * 10 ^ 6 = 27sec` + the cost of calculating distance (triangle, point) for each point

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by [*La Lune De Idees*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019022/5411817) is a very good starting point. Thanks to the answer I was able to speed up my code by 30x through using only numpy and scipy.

Given

`vertice_points` a mesh as M x 3 numpy array

and

`point_cloud` a point cloud as N x 3 numpy array to calculate the distances to

I came up with the full (for me working) example below:

```
# make efficient search tree
tree = cKDTree(vertice_points)

# get indices of closest three points to use as vetice to calculate distance to
d, idx_of_point_in_mesh = tree.query(point_cloud, 3)

# anchor point to span a plane from
anchor_points = vertice_points[idx_of_point_in_mesh[:,0],:]

# use next two nearest points to span a plane with two vectors
# from anchor point
plane_points = vertice_points[idx_of_point_in_mesh[:,1:],:]
plane_vecs = np.array(plane_points)
plane_vecs[:,0,:] -= anchor_points
plane_vecs[:,1,:] -= anchor_points

# calculate normal vectors of the planes
normals = np.cross(plane_vecs[:,0,:], plane_vecs[:,1,:], axis=1)

# distance from each point to its anchor point for spanning a plane
PQ = anchor_points - point_cloud
# distance is dot product between normal and PQ vector
# since normals and PQ are arrays of vectors 
# use einsum to calc dot product along first dimension
dists = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', PQ, normals)
```

**NOTE**: The code above assumes that the vertice spanned by the three nearest points in the mesh is also the nearest vertice to the point, which is a reasonable assumption, if the mesh is relatively flat and the points are close to the center of the mesh, and not far distanced relative to the extend of the mesh. Which is the case for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment, but if I am not mistaken, [Tobi's very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68862638/5411817) is lacking normalization of the normal vectors, resulting in wrong absolute distance-values. This can be solved using [`np.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
normals = np.cross(plane_vecs[:, 0, :], plane_vecs[:, 1, :], axis=1)
normals_norm = normals / (np.linalg.norm(normals, ord=2, axis=1)[:, None])
```

Also, be aware that the sign of the distances is not giving a direction of the distance.